Are associations classes in class diagrams like weak entities in ERD?
I am trying to understand better UML with the help of my knowledge of entity-relationship modeling.
How do association classes work in the class diagram? I understand that they have their own characteristics but differ from other classes because they represent a connection.
So can they be considered as weak entities in a certain sense?

A class diagram just visualizes the association class. "class of association" does mean something completely different.

Have you read anything regarding the association classes, for instance the UML specification. It's pretty well described there.

I have edited slightly your question to make it more understandable for people who are not necessarily familiar with entity modeling.  I hope this is ok for you, if not just rollback to the previous version or edit further.

An UML association class is at the same time an association and a class. Since it is also a class, it means that its instances have their own identity. Since it is also an association, the existance of the link depends on the existance of the linked instances.
An ERD weak entity is an entity that depends on the existance of another entity, and  whose identity makes only sense together with the identity of that other entity.
These are therefore two independent and unrelated concepts. You could for example implement an association class in a relational database scheme that could be modelled in ERD as a strong entity, with a surrogate key and total participation with the associated entities or as a weak entity with a compound key including at least one of the owning entity's key.
The closest concept to an association class in ERD is the associative entity.

Association classes should be treated as normal classes.
A class is simply a class. A new class is added because it is inappropriate for certain features to be maintained by other classes. Association classes are added for this reason—to maintain the details of associations.
Isn't this applicable to other classes as well? Consider the "Order" class, for instance. Although it might not be regarded as an "association class," it can indeed be seen as an association class between "Customer" and "Product."
It is unpredictable whether the current "association classes" will evolve into classes that play significant roles in the future.
